# How can Django handle big dropdown list without front end scripts?

Tags: django

Problem is simple, dropdown fields based on foreign key  eventually   can become very big and it is difficult to select needed value for end user.

Of course it is possible to manage those using front end scripts, however is there anything in django  "batteries included" that can solve this without going into Javascript too much ?

Comment: Pure front end stuff: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you end up with large drop down lists you could look to [Select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) as a solution as it offers a text field with auto completion, amongst other widgets.

The auto complete type widget I mention works like this;

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choice = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=MyOtherModel,
            search_fields=['title__icontains']
        )
    )
```